# suggest a autocomplete with multi select textbox in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 4. Can anyone please suggest a autocomplete with multi select. I found some example normal angular. http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/XbH[aZSiYqEzxjk6TuWyj/](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/XbHaZSiYqEzxjk6TuWyj/)  I need autocomplete like the first one in the link

Comment: Angular Material Autocomplete https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: You want multiple autocompletes and inputs linked?

Comment: I'm just getting started, but after an initial review, this is what I've found and liked best as an Angular chips/multi-select with auto-complete potential:
[NGX-Chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally used it in 2 - 3 projects. You can reach out to me if need any help in it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: I tried angular2-multiselect-dropdown. But on selecting one item, all items are getting selected and clicking on another item will deselect everything

Comment: Can you please share the following code with me: dropdownsetting, Form code and array you are passing to multiselect.

Comment: this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      text: "Select Tag(s) for Your Post",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      enableSearchFilter: true,
      classes: "myclass custom-class"
    };

Comment: this._teamSpaceService.getAllTags()
      .subscribe(tags => {
        this.dropdownList = tags;
       
      },
      error => this.errorMessage);

Comment: getAllTags(): Observable<ITeamSpace[]> {       
       
        return this._http.get(this._allTagsUrl)
            .map(res => res as ITags[] || [])
            .map(post => post.map(this.toTags))           
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

Comment: can you give me this.dropdownList object values because multiselect only supports the follwing array  let someArray = [{ id: 1, itemName: 'a' }, { id: 2, itemName: 'b'}]; means object should have id and itemName in it.

Comment: 0:{itemName: "Digital Strategy"}
1:{itemName: "Design"}
2:{itemName: "Creative Strategy"}
3:{itemName: "Web 2.0"}

Comment: i dont have any id field

Comment: just pass id: 'same as itemName' in it.0:{itemName: "Digital Strategy", id:  "Digital Strategy"} 1:{itemName: "Design", id: "Design"} 2:{itemName: "Creative Strategy", id: "Creative Strategy"} 3:{itemName: "Web 2.0", id:  "Web 2.0"}

Comment: it worked. Thanks..